# Using `-ftrivial-auto-var-init` to guarantee the initialization of padding bytes to zero for non-static aggregate objects

Tags: c++, initialization, g++, clang++, zero-initialization

I'm following [Does C++ standard guarantee the initialization of padding bytes to zero for non-static aggregate objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70979077/does-c-standard-guarantee-the-initialization-of-padding-bytes-to-zero-for-non) and trying to *force* GCC and Clang to initialize padding with zero. The [`-ftrivial-auto-var-init=choice`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-ftrivial-auto-var-init) flag seems to do the trick, but I don't see any difference between using it or not

The original code is [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Yn39vMTWd) (without using `-ftrivial-auto-var-init=zero`), and produces non-zeroed members:

#### GCC

```
Foo():
x:[----][0x42][0x43][0x44],v: 0
y:[----][----][----][----],v: 0
z:[----][0x4A][0x4B][0x4C],v: 0

Foo{}:
x:[----][----][----][----],v: 0
y:[----][----][----][----],v: 0
z:[----][----][----][----],v: 0
```

#### Clang

```
Foo():
x:[----][----][----][----],v: 0
y:[----][----][----][----],v: 0
z:[----][----][----][----],v: 0

Foo{}:
x:[----][0x42][0x43][0x44],v: 0
y:[----][----][----][----],v: 0
z:[----][0x4A][0x4B][0x4C],v: 0
```

I've added the `-ftrivial-auto-var-init=zero` flag to [both GCC 12 and Clang 15](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/r3PvqMbna). but the results are exactly the same, so I'm a bit confused as to what `-ftrivial-auto-var-init=zero` should do.

#### GCC

```
Foo():
x:[----][0x42][0x43][0x44],v: 0
y:[----][----][----][----],v: 0
z:[----][0x4A][0x4B][0x4C],v: 0

Foo{}:
x:[----][----][----][----],v: 0
y:[----][----][----][----],v: 0
z:[----][----][----][----],v: 0
```

#### Clang

```
Foo():
x:[----][----][----][----],v: 0
y:[----][----][----][----],v: 0
z:[----][----][----][----],v: 0

Foo{}:
x:[----][0x42][0x43][0x44],v: 0
y:[----][----][----][----],v: 0
z:[----][0x4A][0x4B][0x4C],v: 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `-ftrivial-auto-var-init` only applies to automatic variables (like the name suggests):

> Initialize **automatic** variables with either a pattern or with zeroes to increase the security and predictability of a program by preventing uninitialized memory disclosure and use.

Automatic variables are variables that have [*automatic storage duration*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.stc.auto), i.e. local block-scope variables only.

Note that if you're using `new` / `delete` then your objects will have [*dynamic storage duration*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.stc.dynamic) and therefore `-ftrivial-auto-var-init` will not apply to them.

---

##### Example

This example demonstrates the effect of `-ftrivial-auto-var-init=zero`:
[godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aTG3za4hr)

```cpp
struct Foo
{
    char x;
    int y;
    char z;
};

int main()
{
    {
        char buf[sizeof(Foo)];
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(buf); ++i)
        {
            buf[i] = 'A' + i;
        }
        buf[sizeof(Foo)-1] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", buf);
    }
    {
        Foo f;
        DumpF("Foo, automatic", &f);
    }
}
```

When compiled with `-ftrivial-auto-var-init=zero` you're guaranteed to get:

```
Foo, automatic:
x:[----][----][----][----],v: 0
y:[----][----][----][----],v: 0
z:[----][----][----][----],v: 0
```

Whereas if you compile without it you'll most likely get random bytes from the stack (in this case gcc chose to reuse the space of `buf`):

```
Foo, automatic:
x:[0x41][0x42][0x43][0x44],v: 65
y:[0x45][0x46][0x47][0x48],v: 1212630597
z:[0x49][0x4A][0x4B][----],v: 73
```